# module no encontrado Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

estoy haciendo rutas para una app en react, estoy importando el componente "layout" a "navbar" pero me sale el siguiente error

**Failed to compile
./src/componentes/shared/navbar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './componentes/routers/layouts'**. estoy tratando de ver porque no me encuentra ese modulo en particular quizas, me he saltado la importacion de algun componente quizas.

LAYOUT:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';



export class Layout extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(

        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/home' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/servicios' component={Servicios} />
            <Route exact path='/contacto' component={Contacto} />
        </Switch>

    );
 }
}
```

NAVBAR:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './componentes/routers/layouts';

export const NavBar = () => {
return(
    <div>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <Link to='/' className="navbar-brand">App_test</Link>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item active">
                <Link to='/home' className="nav-link">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to='/servicios' className="nav-link">Servicios</Link>
            </li>

            <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to='contacto' className="nav-link">Contacto</Link>
            </li>

            </ul>
            <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
            <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    </div>
);
}
```

Esta es la distribucion de las carpetas utilizadas dentro de mi proyecto, algo simple.

```
 _src
  _componentes
    _routers 
     - layouts.js

    _shared
     - contacto.js
     - footer.js
     - navbar.js
     - home.js
     - servicios.js

app.js
index.js
```

Comment: podrías mostrar como están distribuidas las carpetas y archivos de tu proyecto para tener una visión mas amplia?

Comment: @nauseantparrot ahi amigo esta editada!

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo en cuenta la distribución de archivos y carpetas que muestras, el problema es que estas intentando buscar tu archivo `layouts.js` en la ruta `/src/componentes/shared/routers/layouts.js` debido a que le especificas que lo busque a partir de la carpeta actual, para que sea posible lograr lo que deseas, debes indicarle que primero salga de la carpeta actual y luego si vaya a la carpeta routers asi:

```
import { Layout } from '../routers/layouts'
```